# ManyRelatedManager object at [XXX] is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, getjson

I have a simple model with `ManyToManyFields` I am serializing to JSON:

models.py:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_team_members = models.ManyToManyField(Team, blank=False, null=False) # hosts
    meeting_visitors = models.ManyToManyField(Visitor, blank=False, null=False) # invited guests
```

views.py:

```
instances = Meeting.objects.filter(site=site.id)

for ins in instances: #populate list
     context.append({
        'meeting_title': ins.meeting_title, 
        'meeting_team_members':ins.meeting_team_members.all, 
        'meeting_visitors': ins.meeting_visitors.all, 

json_context = json.dumps(context, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder) #dump list as JSON
return HttpResponse(json_context, 'application/javascript')
```

However I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError at /dashboard/get_meetings/
<django.db.models.fields.related.create_many_related_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x03406730> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You need to use some sort of serializer. It is having touble serializing `meeting_team_members` to json. Have you considered using[`django-rest-framework`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build your api? It has some really nice classes to build serializers.

Comment: @Brobin yes, but this is a single usecase so `django-rest-framework` seems a bit overkill. Is there another way around this?

Comment: Have you tried changing `ins.meeting_team_members.all` to `ins.meeting_team_members.all()`? etc. So the function is called?

Comment: @Brobin yes, the error is then `[<Visitor: visitor2>] is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If @Brobin suggestion doesn't help for some reason ...

```
meeting_team_members = [x.as_dict() for x in ins.meeting_team_members.all()]

class Team(models.Model):
    # ... example fields
    def as_dict(self):
        context = {
            'pk': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
        }

        if self.image:
            context['image'] = get_thumbnail(self.image, '150').url
            context['full_image'] = self.image.url
        else:
            context['no_image'] = _(u'No image)  # this is just for localization

        return context
```

### EDIT

```
for ins in instances: #populate list
     context.append({
        'meeting_title': ins.meeting_title, 
        'meeting_team_members':[x.as_dict() for x in ins.meeting_team_members.all()]
     })
```

Comment: thanks, please could you explain the logic here? what is the problem you are solving and how are you doing it? thanks

Comment: I am actually serializing object in `as_dict` to JSON (acceptable format) ... updated answer

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how the `as_dict(self)` in the model relates to `meeting_team_members`? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: actually `ins.meeting_team_members.all()` returns all related to current instance `Team` objects ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I have tried applying this code and it results in `'Team' object has no attribute 'as_dict'`

Comment: Have you added this method to `Team` class like in example above? :)